# How to get in Python the api called by the frontpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

Everything is in the tilte.

I am using `requests.get(website, headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies)` to get the content of the website. `website` calls APIs to get the data. I would like to know the URL of the APIs called by `website`. Is it possible to do so in Python ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? [Please provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't tried a lot of stuff yet. Only got the content from the html with `BeautifulSoup`.


```soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")``` But what I really want is to get all the call to APIs. In Chrome browser I navigated to XHR and I found them.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use python to make the same call to the api that the website is. You didn't post any specifics, but it would be similar to what you've already done

```
requests.get(apiurl, headers=apiheaders, params=apiparams)
#may or may not need cookies
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But actually I don't know the API url until I open the url first. That's why I need to know if it's possible to get all the call to other urls in Python.

Comment: What do you mean? Is the api url dynamic or something?

Comment: Not really. To give more explanation: there is the front page that display the information (this is the URL I know and I can iterate over). And the front page calls backend apis to get the data. It makes a `GET` request. I am looking for a way in Python to know those `GET`call

Comment: You can make those `GET` requests the same way your browser does. You should be able to inspect and see all the headers and params it's passing and use those